# What is the diametral pitch for a gear rack with 32 teeth per in?

Tags: gears

I am trying to order a gear rack with 32 teeth per inch. I can't seem to get my math right to figure out the diametral pitch for a gear rack with 32 teeth per inch.

Comment: Where did your 32 teeth per inch requirement come from? If your pinion is "32 pitch" (number of teeth per inches of pitch diameter), the rack needs to be the same i.e. 32 diametral pitch

Comment: The 32 teeth per in comes from the need to use two racks face to face for indexing. (like in the picture: https://incra.com/images/p_incratracks_body2_zoom.png) I am not using it in the tradiational rack and pinion use case.

Comment: You will not be able to use a standard pitch gear rack then as you are looking for a gear with circumferential pitch of 32. Inch-standard gears use diametral pitch so you are off by a factor of pi. This is an advantage of metric gears, in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time, but the way I remember:

The diametrical pitch is the number of teeth in the gear for each inch of pitch diameter.

For example, if you have a gear with a diameter of 2.5 inches and a diametrical pitch of 32. Then, N, the number of the teeth is.

Note the pitch circle in the diagram. That is where the diameter is measured.

$$N=P*D =32D=32*2.5=80$$

'

[image: pitch circle]

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: If I am not mistaken (I am used to SI - so please check derivation below)  it's just **$32\cdot \pi$.**

---

### Derivation

The Diametral Pitch is defined as the number of teeth divided by the diameter in inches.

$$P =\frac{N}{D}$$

where:

- N is the number of teeth
- D is the Pitch diameter

However the circumference of the Gear would be $\pi\cdot D$. Therefore the "density" of the teeth per inch over the circumference (which should be equal to 32) would be

$$32\left[\frac{\text{teeth}}{in}\right] = \frac{N}{\pi\cdot D}$$
$$32\left[\frac{\text{teeth}}{in}\right] = \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{N}{\cdot D}$$
$$32\left[\frac{\text{teeth}}{in}\right] \cdot\pi =  \frac{N}{ D} = P$$